# Active Record find conditions as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i have some conditions to pass to a finder. The problem is that i don't want to pass in an usafety way. So imagine that i receive a hash:

```
hash = {:start_date=>'2009-11-01',:end_date=>'2010-01-23'}
```

i would like to pass it to my finder like:

```
Model.find(:all,:conditions=>"created > '#{start_date}' and created < '#{end_date}'")
```

The problem is that it is unsafe and i'm exposed to SQL injection problems. My question is, how would be the best way to compose this condition?

I want to do it dynamically. For example, i'm doing today like:

```
find_condition = ['created > ? and created < ?','2009-10-01','2010-01-01']
Model.find(:all,:conditions=>find_condition)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
Model.find(:all,:conditions=>["created > :start_date and created < :end_date", {:start_date => params[:one], :end_date => params[:two]}])
```

It will be escaped properly.

Answer (score 1):

Active Record supports escaping of conditions using a question mark:

```
Model.all(:conditions => ['created > ? and created < ?',
          :start_date, :end_date])
```

Some further information in the Rails' Guides that you may be interested in:

- [Active Record Query Interface: Conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions)
- [Security Guide: SQL Injection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)

Comment: @JohnTopley I think that should actually be `Model.all(:conditions => ['created > ? and created < ?', :start_date, :end_date])`. (i.e. don't the conditions belong in the `[]` as well?)

Comment: I believe you meant start_date, end_date instead of :start_date, :end_date (colons out)

Comment: Interesting - how is that possible? Wouldn't the '?' be just replaced by the text 'start_date' and 'end_date' respectively?